# Python/MatPlot Save Graph Objects to One File

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a program that reads data in from SQL server, passes it to an object class via a loop, creates 6 graphs as objects, and saves each to a file. I'm trying to save all to the same file (file type does not matter PDF, jpg, etc.)

```
#main
...
data = pd.dataframe(pd.read_sql("Select * from FOO", cnxn)
for i in range(1,7):
    graph = GraphObject(i, data)
    graph.func()

#GraphObject class
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from datetime import date, timedelta

class GraphObject:
    i = -1
    data = ()

    def __init__(self,i,data):
        self.i = i
        self.data = data

    def func(self):
        canvassDateVar = date.today() - timedelta (days = self.i)
        filteredData = self.data[(self.data.CanvassDate == str(canvassDateVar))]

        cityAgeRange = list(filteredData["CityAgeRange"])
        signedUpPercent = list(filteredData["SignedUpPercent"])
        didNotSignUpPercent = list(filteredData["DidNotSignUpPercent"])
        tookSurvey = list(filteredData["TakeSurvey"])
        
        D = np.array(signedUpPercent)
        E = np.array(didNotSignUpPercent)
        F = np.array(tookSurvey)

        fig = plt.figure()
        pos = range(len(cityAgeRange))
        plt.xticks(pos, cityAgeRange, size = 'small')
        plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
        plt.ylabel('Percentages of Answers')
        plt.xlabel('City and Age Group')
        plt.title('Data Dive for ' + str(canvassDateVar), fontsize=14)
        plt.ylim([0, 200])

        plt.bar(pos, D)
        plt.bar(pos, E, bottom = D)

        plt.legend(['SignedUp', 'NotSignedUp'], loc = 0)

        ax2 = plt.twinx()
        ax2.plot(F, color = 'black')
        ax2.set_ylabel('Number of Surveys Taken')
        fileName = "Data " + str(canvassDateVar) + ".png"
        fig.savefig(fileName)

    def figure(self):
        plt.figure()
```

I've tried every solution I can find on StackOverflow and through searching the internet (printing to PDF, subplotting, creating an array then saving from the array, etc.), but none are working for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI,

While awaiting answers, I decided to try a different approach by reading the created .png files into a pdf versus creating one document plotting or displaying the objects themselves. This is what worked for me if anyone is researching this in the future and wanting different options:

```
from PIL import Image
from fpdf import FPDF

graphArray = []
pdf = FPDF()
w, h = 0, 0

data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_sql("SELECT *...", cnxn))

for i in range(1, 8):
    graph = GraphObject(i, data)
    graphArray.append(graph.func())
    fname = graphArray[i-1]
    if os.path.exists(fname):
        if i == 1:
            cover = Image.open(fname)
            w, h = cover.size
            pdf = FPDF(unit = "pt", format = [w, h])
        image = fname
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.image(image, 0, 0, w, h)
    else:
        print("File not found:", fname)
    print("processed %d" % i)
pdf.output("output.pdf", "F")
print("done")
```

This solution found here: https://prahladyeri.com/blog/2019/10/python-recipe-combine-images-pdf.html

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using subplots?  You could pass a subplot to the constructor and write to it with each func() call.  If you'd like to avoid that route, another option is to just export to HTML (not advised, MPLd3 does not recreate perfectly always), or you could export to a powerpoint and save the slide afterwards as an image.

I don't think either of the alternatives are good ideas.  This sounds like the perfect use case for subplots.

Comment: All the examples I've found re: subplots are passing plot coordinates into the argument (for example and off the top of my head so definitely not exact syntax):
x = tan 1;
y = 1;
fig.subplot(x, y);

I can't find/figure out how do do that with my more complicated program, multiple y axis, objects, etc.

Comment: How I envisioned it was instead of passing coords, you'd create a figure, i.e. fig = plt.subplots(6,1) from outside the main for loop, then modify func() to take in a fig (or you could do this part in the constructor) and two coords, i.e. func(fig, x, y), and draw to that coordinate in the subplot.

Comment: Additional details: if I try passing the object or figure into the subplot I get a TypeError: float() argument must be a string or number, not ....... (figure, object, etc.). I tried modifying the object and function to pass in the fig and axs and plot them,  but that errored out as well.